# Google Places API - How to retrieve only places added through my app?

Tags: google-places-api

I am currently exploring the Google Places API for an Android application of mine. What I would basically like to do is to add a bunch of specific places to Google Places, then be able to retrieve them, and *only them*, through the API.

In other words, I don't want the search queries to return places that exist outside of my application, as they would not be relevant 99% of the time.

I don't see a simple way to do this, other than adding a specific keyword to the name of the place and then look for places that have that word--but that sounds a bit cheesy.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: The Google Places API does not currently support this feature. If you believe this would be a useful feature you can submit a `Places API - Feature Request` here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Places for Android API deprecated alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638080/places-for-android-api-deprecated-alternative)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the places that you add in a private database. Then provide these as the 'Universe'. You can't use Google places api.