# PlaceAutoComplete over query imit

Tags: android, google-places-api

Error while autocompleting: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

I got this error in autocomplet. error came at first request of the day. please help me to recover this

Comment: Do you have the proper api key?

Comment: Do you have billing enabled in your project? It is mandatory for Google Maps Platform.

Comment: Proper API key submitted and the key is worked in previous version PlaceAuto Complete

Comment: i have proper key but i did not purchase google cloud platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to purchase the google cloud platform for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

> Please enable Billing account so that you can acess Places API,
>   without billing account only one request is permitted.

For guidelines:https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045772/10579969