# Setting Place Fields error while using PlaceAutoCompleteFragment using new Google Places SDK

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Currently following Google's new [guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) on using Google Places using a Fragment however.

Despite setting

```
autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));
```

It brings up

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Place Fields must be set.
```

Currently this is my code.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        autocompleteFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Start");
            Places.initialize(getActivity(), String.valueOf(R.string.google_api_key));

        }


        if (autocompleteFragment != null) {
            autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));
        }

        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));


        // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onError: Error:" + status);
            }


        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Places SDK has been Depricated You need to migrate to new **PLACES API**.
>   You can find solution by the below tguideline.

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045772/10579969**