# New Google Places SDK doesnt fetch user selection in Android

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I am using the new Google Places SDK: AutocompleteSupportFragment.

whenever i select an address from the result list it doesn't save it and show it on the field.

I am not sure why.

this is my code below:
i declaed the variable at the top of the class:

```
Place shipAddress;
```

and called this method where i needed:

```
        final AutocompleteSupportFragment editAddress = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
        editAddress.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

        editAddress.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                shipAddress = place;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Log.e("ERROR", status.getStatusMessage());
            }
        });
```

i am also using the result in another method calling:

```
address = shipAddress.getAddress().toString();
```

but finally i get an error that 
variable address is invoked on a null object.

Answer (score 0):

> Places SDK has been Depricated You need to migrate to new **PLACES
>   API**.. You can find solution by below guideline.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045772/10579969

**`Official page`** https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#place_picker