# How to display nearby locations using Google Places API as a list (without a map) for a flutter project?

Tags: flutter, google-places-api

I'm building a ***flutter*** app which should show the nearby locations of the user as a list. I have used ***locations*** plugin to find the user's location, which now returns latitude and longitude.

Is it possible using this information (lat & long) to show the nearby locations as a list, not using a map?

Comment: You can use Places API.. Autocomplete for serarching places Nearby https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045772/10579969

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) :

Use `location` property to pass lat and long.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, use Google Places API
**https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search**

Use location property to pass lat lng as suggested in the documentation link provided.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without the location package?