# How can I use GoogleMap SDK to list nearby places?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to implement Map activity. I need to show nearby places using Google map SDK. I don't know how to use Google Map SDK because I'm a beginner.

I try many tutorial all of that use HTTP URL. I need to use Google Map SDK. Near by places search with keywords like ATM, BANK etc with specified radius.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    double C_Latitude, C_Longitude;
    PlacesClient placesClient;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 1;
    String keyword="atm";
    String radius="1000"; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(),"@string/key");
        placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            }
        } else {
            fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {
                            C_Latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            C_Longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            LatLng CurrntLocation = new LatLng(C_Latitude, C_Longitude);
                            CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CurrntLocation, 19);  //zoom
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CurrntLocation).title("Current Position"));  //marker
                            mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
                            GetNearbyPlace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    private void GetNearbyPlace() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Places SDK is deprecated, please migrate to new **PLACES API**

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#place_picker

- First you need enable PlacesAPI in developer console (you should   enable billing account).
- Then implement Places API in your gradle.

for **Autocomplete Places** follow below guideline

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045772/10579969**

Comment: How to use this to find near atm, hotels etc

Comment: http://androidmastermind.blogspot.com/2016/06/android-google-maps-with-nearyby-places.html This may help you

Comment: Brother this is not what i need, in this tutorial he used HTTP URL for retrieve nearby places. I need SDK for retrieve nearby places, is that possible ?

Comment: https://www.mytrendin.com/display-nearby-places-banks-using-google-maps-api-in-android/

Comment: its also use URL brother. i need to use sdk find near atm within certain radius. is it possible with sdk.