# Address picker Android

Tags: android, geolocation, geocoding, google-location-services

[image]

I want to do same like attached photo. Where user can search or choose current location.

Comment: You need to use `google cloud places web api` ... this feature can't gained using `geocoding`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Google Places API,

- Place picker
- Autocomplete

please refer below link 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045772/10579969

Place pickar can be implement by two ways

- -Fragment
- -IntentBuilder