# Google Places api will deprecate or not?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Google places SDK will get deprecated
As Google announced "Deprecation notice: Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android" so will it affect on this API (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json) which I am using in my project with the help of google play services. for getting predictions regarding the autocomplete address.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete

Comment: Hope it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56375310/4524195

Answer (score 1):

Please note that URI `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json` doesn't form part of the Places SDK for Android. This URI belongs to the Google Places API web service.

Web service wasn't deprecated and will continue working as usual. If your application executes direct calls to web services there is nothing to worry about. You should only migrate old code that uses methods of Places SDK for Android to new SDK.

I hope this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's deprecated and it will be turned off on July 29, 2019

> Notice: The Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android (in Google Play Services 16.0.0) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019, and will be turned off on July 29, 2019. A new version of the Places SDK for Android is now available. We recommend updating to the new version as soon as possible. For details, see the migration guide.

see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) , also see the new way to implement it in the documentation .