# Do I need to enable billing for new Places compatibility library android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-places-api

As new version of the Places SDK for Android is introduced, it gives two options to integrate it.

1. Use the [Places SDK static client library](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#install_the_client_library) (Requires API key)
2. [Compatibility Library](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#install_the_compatibility_library) (Does not require API Key)

When using the compatibility library, is it important to enable the Places API in the Google Cloud Console for the project and enable billing? It seems to be working fine without enabling it also.

The documentation states that:

> The compatibility library only supports newer Task-based APIs, and will not work with the earlier PendingResult model.

But it still works with the `PendingResult` model. Is it important to change to `Task` based?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you have to enable biiling account, so that if you use any another API in future for this project by only billing account you can able to use that API's..**

**example:** For directions API only one request is allowed without    billing account, so have to go for billing account...

Comment: can we just use placeAutoComplete only enabling Google Places API and not enabling billing account. Is it necessary to eneble billing or just enebling places api will do my work for places autocomplete. provide proper guidance or documentation. thanks in advance.

Comment: For only Places API,  just go withot billing account. for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045772/10579969

Comment: Places api requires billing account now

Comment: Yes u need billing account