# How can i clear text of selected Place name from AutocompleteSupportFragment?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, google-places-api

i create my project for ride booking app. I use AutocompleteSupportFragment for search place . After selecting Place , i filter that location if you are in Delhi then set Text of AutocompleteSupportFragment other wise set Hint like "Please select valid place".

I try

```
autocompleteFragment_to.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {

            if (!getStateName(place.getLatLng().latitude, place.getLatLng().longitude).equals("Madhya Pradesh")) {
                Common.myLatLong = null;
                Common.placeName1 = null;
                Common.placeName1City = null;
                Log.e("FRagmentData",""+autocompleteFragment_to.a.getText().toString());
                autocompleteFragment_to.a.getText().toString();
                autocompleteFragment_to.a.setText("");
                autocompleteFragment_to.a.setHint("Please select Valid Place");
                autocompleteFragment_to.getView().findViewById(R.id.places_autocomplete_clear_button).performClick();
                autocompleteFragment_to.a.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please select Valid Place", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                destination = place.getLatLng();
                Common.myLatLong = place.getLatLng();
                Common.placeName1 = place.getName();
                Log.e("FRagmentData",""+autocompleteFragment_to.a.getText().toString());
                Common.placeName1City = getAddress(context, place.getLatLng().latitude, place.getLatLng().longitude);
                if (mMap != null) {
                    mMap.clear();
                }
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I try all these approch but it's not working

Comment: You can also help me out if u can

Comment: @user1241241 this is my updated quetion.

Answer (score 0):

**Use AutoComplete IntentBuilder instead of fragment..**

Just initialise Places inside oncreate()

```
// Initialize Places.
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "***YOUR API KEY***");

   // Create a new Places client instance.
   PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
```

then call intentbuilder in textview.onclick()

```
List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);
// Start the autocomplete intent.
Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
        AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
        .build(this);
startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

onActivity result you will get selected place.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
        } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
            Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
```

After that, just set the selected place in the Textview.

```
Textview.setText(place.getName());
```

refer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045772/10579969