# Migrating to the New Places SDK Client in an old application

Tags: android, android-volley, google-places

I'm trying to migrate to new sdk client inside an application.
When I tried to introduce the implementation inside my build.gradle the application throws an exception. What can I do to solve it?

What I have tried:

I have included inside build.gradle the following implementation

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'
```

also I have tried with

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

both of them throws the following error

```
Unable to resolve dependency for project : Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1.
```

Is anything I can do to make it compatible?
What are the changes I need to do?

Here is my build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/volley.jar')
    implementation('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
        implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
    }
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    annotationProcessor 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.amber:amber-oauth2-client:0.22-incubating'
    implementation 'org.apache.amber:amber-oauth2-common:0.22-incubating'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
}
```

project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'

            }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045772/10579969 refer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify if you have this repository added in your app level gradle file

```
allprojects {

    repositories {
         jcenter()
    }
}
```

Also change this line

```
implementation files('libs/volley.jar')
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

As you are facing issue `Program type already present: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError`

Add this in your app dir build.gradle

```
android{
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.volley'
}}
```

Comment: I have tried changing implementation files('libs/volley.jar') for implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0' and the error continue happening

Comment: did you add `jcenter()` in your allprojects repositories '

Comment: I have added to jcenter() and the error at least has change :D Now it shows Error: Program type already present: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

Comment: I have updated the answer try that now. if it doesn't work. Go in libs folder and delete the volley.jar . You don't need that. Yes! you should make its backup anyway

Comment: add  all*.exclude group: 'com.android.volley' save my day! All start working again! Thank you sooo much Derek